# Can't connect to fresh mysql; password issue?

Tags: mysql, linux, passwords, lamp

I'm new to setting up my own database server and linux server, but I'm working on a project that needs to use phpCake and mysql. I have a turnkey linux install of LAMP, with phpCake installed on it. My Cake install is fine, however I can not get into mysql.

mysql command yields error 1045, access denied for user root@localhost using password: no
mysql -u root -p
'rootpasswordhere'
yeilds the same thing, except using password:yes

I've read many fixes involving stoping mysql and setting a new password. I've had none of those work for me. The mysql stop command is denied in the same way the mysql command is. When I use service stop mysql my input cursor gets strange and no longer captures any input.

I'd love any help or input. I'll try out any of the fixes out there again and detail what happens. I'm sorry if this has been answered before, but trying the fixes I've found over the last few hours don't seem to work. Unsure if it is me, or my actual problem.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried not using a password or a blank password?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that. Tried it again and doesn't work.

Comment: Well there is always resetting the root password manually: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I may have to try that. To be honest, it seems a bit over my head. My experience is very limited in this field.

Comment: It is quite simple just follow the instructions a) stop service, b) start service with flag to skip permissions c) connect to mysql and update password d) restart service normally

Comment: I've tried that several times. I stop the mysql process then follow commands to do exactly that, however usually after the first command to stop the service my prompt goes blank, and I get no response to my commands so I have no idea of they go through, and it never works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which linux you are running:

**Stop service:**

`sudo service mysqld stop`

**Run these commands to write a temporary SQL file (/tmp/my.sql):**

> sudo echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';" > /tmp/my.sql
>   sudo echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> /tmp/my.sql

**Start the service with script:**

`sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --init-file=/tmp/my.sql &`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ *The ampersand runs the process in the background allowing you to continue using the terminal.*

Now you should be able to connect with your new root password *MyNewPass*

**Note:** Be sure to a) change the root password and b) remove /tmp/my.sql once completed.

Comment: "service mysqld stop" yeilds "mysqld: unrecognized service" when I try to Run it. service stop mysql works though, but not mysqld.

Comment: Also, when I do run that script file it says that "A mysqld process already exists", but service mysqld status says unrecognized serivce. How is that possible?

Comment: `sudo killall mysqld` to kill the process thats already running. What flavor of linux are you running? Type `uname -a` to find out. `mysql` is usually the client program not the server.

Comment: I'm running this - http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack. Sudo isn't a command bash recognizes. What part of uname -a is useful? killall mysqld seemed to run, but when i use mysqld_safe --init-file=/tmp/my.sql it still says a mysqld process already exists.

Comment: Did you try the password **root** or **turnkey** ? http://www.gigatux.com/faq.php?question=22